# Are there any preset I18n word lists / resource files?

Tags: dictionary, internationalization, translation

I'm creating a web application that uses I18n. As I don't want to translate very common basic strings like "forgot password?" on my own I'm asking you if there are already any resource files or word lists containing these strings. One option is to download an existing framework and extract somehow these strings but this might be a hassle?
Especially I'm looking for translation regarding user authentication and translations from English to Italian, French and German. The file format doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professional translators use a tool, TMX is the generic term i think, Translation Memory Exchange, that does what you are talking about by building up standard phrase lists in other languages so when they translate they can bring these phrases in to speed up their job and reduce the repetitive tedium. So these lists exist.

There is a free plugin for MS Word that does this and may come with lists (sorry cannot remember the name although Rosetta rings a bell).

There is an FOSS TMX tool called Okapi at Sourceforge. It may come with the dictionaries  but if not it is a point where you can investigate.

You could also approach a site called Proz which is a site for translators and might be able to point you in the right direction

Take care over MT like Google API as it can give some weird results but you could use it to build you list and then double check. Remember that when you check a language that you need to do it with a native speaker who can pick up on the nuances and colloquialisms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google translator api. and your custom resource bundle

Comment: yes, that's one option. the downsides of using these online dictionaries are that they don't always provide a correct translation and it still requires a lot of manual work